# $2$ by $2$ equation system where the desired variables are inside trigonometrics functions

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

In this equation system, $X$ and $Y$ are known, I need to have $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$ (if I change $X$ and $Y$, what values do $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have?).

$$
X=60.5*\cos(  \beta  )-60*\cos(  \alpha  )
\\
Y=60.5*\sin(  \beta  )-60*\sin(  \alpha  )
$$

I started by getting $\beta$ from the first formula:

$$
  \beta =\arccos\left(\frac{\mathrm{X+60*\cos( \alpha )} }{\mathrm{60.5}}\right) 
$$

But when you substitute $\beta$ in the second equations things get complicated very fast:

$$
  Y=60.5*\sin\left(  \arccos\left(\frac{\mathrm{X+60*cos( \alpha )} }{\mathrm{60.5}}\right)  \right)-60*\sin(  \alpha  )
$$

I can apply the identity $  \sin(\arccos(x))= \sqrt{1-x^2} $ but that just keep complicating the equation.

Am I doing this correctly? Is it that complicated?

**EDIT**

Following the suggested answers, by squaring the equation an adding them up and applying some trigonometric identities, I get this expression:

$$
 \alpha  -  \beta =  \arccos ( \frac{\mathrm{7260.25-X^2-Y^2} }{\mathrm{7260}} )
$$

Wich is the cleanest I got so far. But then again, I'm stuck, what can I do now? Are there any other clever manipulations I can do to reduce the system and get another expression of alpha and beta?

Comment: Note that there is no solution if $|X|,|Y|>120.5$. And, there are other combinations of $X,Y$ for which there are no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As you did, squaring and adding, you end with
$$X^2+Y^2=\frac{29041}{4}-7260 \cos (\alpha -\beta )$$ Solve for $\beta$ to get
$$\beta=\alpha +\epsilon \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{29041-4(X^2+Y^2)}{29040}\right)\qquad (\epsilon=\pm 1)$$
Using $\epsilon=+ 1$, plug in the first equation and expand the cosine to get
$$480 X= \left(241-4(X^2+Y^2)\right)\cos (\alpha )-29040 \sqrt{1-\frac{\left( 29041-4(X^2+Y^2)\right)^2}{843321600}}\sin(\alpha )$$ which is a basic trigonometric equation in $\alpha$.

Comment: yep it is a basic trigonometric equation but when I try to solve It gets crazy :) I'm just at 2 A4 sheets full of equations. I just cannot accept this problem is soo long. If you have time I will be glad if you take a look at my recent question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656707/finding-the-reverse-kinematics-of-a-non-linear-system) that's related to this problem, maybe you can find a better solution of what I got

Comment: You must define intermediate variables. Say $A=480X$, $B=241-4(X^2+Y^2)$, $C=..$ to face the simple $A=B \cos(\alpha)+C\sin(\alpha)$. Solve it in terms of $A,B,C$; do not try to replace. I suppose that you use a speadsheet or software

Answer (score 0):

Square and add the two equations. You will get an expression for $\alpha-\beta$. Then you can use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663479/solving-for-alpha-and-beta-in-the-system-x-d-cos-alpha-betah-cos-alph?rq=1). So, yeah. It comes out pretty complicated.

Comment: I did what you suggest and got an expression of alpha and beta, please check my EDIT. But I do not understand where to go from there. I checked the link but I'm lost :(

Answer (score 0):

I would define 
$$
F(\alpha,\beta) = \Big(
X-60.5\cos\beta + 60\cos\alpha
\Big)^2+\Big(
Y-60.5\sin\beta + 60 \sin\alpha
\Big)^2 \geq 0
$$
and then numerically minimize $F(\alpha,\beta)$ globally over $(\alpha,\beta)\in [0,2\pi]\times [0,2\pi]$. Let $(\alpha^*,\beta^*)$ be the locations of the minima. If $F(\alpha^*,\beta^*)>0$ for all minima then the system does not have a solution. If $F(\alpha^*,\beta^*)=0$ then you have your solution.

Comment: I did what you suggest and got an expression of alpha and beta, please check my EDIT. But I do not understand where to go from there.

Comment: I do prefer this edit ! I should do the same as what you propose. Cheers :-)